# Swift 3 Error Handling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling

I have just updated my Xcode and updated my Swift to the newest Version of Swift 3 and I am getting these random errors with my code. Another issue is that when I write the code Xcode is not auto filling it like it used to for example JSONSerialization is not coming up. My errors look something like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

Type ViewController Does Not Conform to Protocol UITableViewDataSource ^^^

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetcharticles()

}

func fetcharticles(){
    let urlrequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=business-insider&sortBy=top&apiKey=06f7a97628c040f7a2002263fa90ac79")!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlrequest) { (data,response,error)
```

Contexual Type For Closure Argument ^^^

```
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        do {

            let json = try JSONSerielization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutablecontainers)


        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
}

 func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as! ArticleCell

    cell.Title.text = "This Is A Test"

    return cell
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


}
```

Consecutive Declarations On A Line Must Be Seperated by ,^^^

None of these errors came up before I converted the Syntax to Swift 3.

Comment: All of these is very easy to fix error, just make sure your function syntax is correct, closure need `in` after `(data,response,error)`

Comment: Just try to rewrite the functions. There are some minor changes in naming conventions in Swift 3. Just use autosuggestion for function names and copy your logic.

Comment: @Tj3n I am still getting an error with the JSONSerialization line of code and same with the ViewController line code.

Comment: @VishalSonawane The Problem is my autosuggestion is not functioning correctly.

Comment: Check your braces `{ ... }`, they do not match. Typo in "JSONSerielization".

Comment: @Luc If your auto suggestion is not working then simply refer table view delegate methods syntax from apple site.